# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in AndroidRuntime

Tags: android, eclipse

Here is the error:

```
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at sample.app.touchsample.TouchsampleActivity.getTouchedViews(TouchsampleActivity.java:365)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at sample.app.touchsample.TouchsampleActivity.dealEvent(TouchsampleActivity.java:78)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at sample.app.touchsample.TouchsampleActivity.onTouch(TouchsampleActivity.java:294)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)

07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3172)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Here is the code for the MainActivity:

```
 package sample.app.touchsample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
//import sample.app.touchsample.TouchsampleActivity.secondDrum.thirdDrum;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class TouchsampleActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{

    
    
    

    MediaPlayer mp;
    SoundPool fx;
    HashMap <Integer, Integer> fxMap;
    
    int sfxId=1;
    int sfxId2=2;
    int sfxId3=3;
    int sfxId4=4;
    
    private Path path = new Path();

    private View parent;

    private final ArrayList[] recentTouchedViewsIndex = new ArrayList[12];

    private final ArrayList[] downTouchedViewsIndex = new ArrayList[12];

    private final ArrayList<View> moveOutsideEnabledViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    
    private final ArrayList<View> multiTouchViews = new ArrayList<View>();

    private int mTouchSlop = 24;
    
    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    //private ImageView imageView1, imageView2 ;
    

    public void addMoveOutsideEnabledViews(final View view) {
        moveOutsideEnabledViews.add(view);
    }
    

    private void dealEvent(final int actionPointerIndex,
            final MotionEvent event, final View eventView,
            final int actionResolved) {
        int rawX, rawY;
        final int location[] = { 0, 0 };
        eventView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        // Log.v("tag", location + "");
        rawX = (int) event.getX(actionPointerIndex) + location[0];
        rawY = (int) event.getY(actionPointerIndex) + location[1];

        final int actionPointerID = event.getPointerId(actionPointerIndex);
        ArrayList<View> hoverViews = getTouchedViews(rawX, rawY);

        if (actionResolved == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            downTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID] = (ArrayList<View>) hoverViews
                    .clone();
        }
        // deletes all views which where not clicked on ActionDown
        if (downTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID] != null) {
            final ArrayList<View> tempViews = (ArrayList<View>) hoverViews
                    .clone();
            tempViews.removeAll(downTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID]);
            hoverViews.removeAll(tempViews);
        }

        if (recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID] != null) {
            final ArrayList<View> recentTouchedViews = recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID];

            final ArrayList<View> shouldTouchViews = (ArrayList<View>) hoverViews
                    .clone();
            if (!shouldTouchViews.containsAll(recentTouchedViews)) {
                shouldTouchViews.removeAll(recentTouchedViews);
                shouldTouchViews.addAll(recentTouchedViews);

                final ArrayList<View> outsideTouchedViews = (ArrayList<View>) shouldTouchViews
                        .clone();
                outsideTouchedViews.removeAll(hoverViews);
            }

            recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID] = hoverViews;
            hoverViews = shouldTouchViews;
        } else {
            recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID] = hoverViews;
        }

        if (actionResolved == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID] = null;
            downTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID] = null;
        }

        dumpEvent(event);
        for (final View view : hoverViews) {
            int x, y;
            view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            x = rawX - location[0];
            y = rawY - location[1];

            // View does not recognize that the Pointer is
            // outside if the Pointer is not far away (>mTouchSlop)
            if (recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID] != null) {
                if (pointInView(x, y, mTouchSlop, view.getWidth(),
                        view.getHeight())) {
                    // Log.v("tag", "added because < mTouchSlop");

                    if (!recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID]
                            .contains(view)) {
                        recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID].add(view);
                    }
                } else if (moveOutsideEnabledViews.contains(view)) {
                    Log.v("tag", "outside but gets event");
                    recentTouchedViewsIndex[actionPointerID].add(view);
                }
            }
            final MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(event.getDownTime(),
                    event.getEventTime(), actionResolved, x, y,
                    event.getPressure(actionPointerIndex),
                    event.getPressure(actionPointerIndex),
                    event.getMetaState(), event.getXPrecision(),
                    event.getYPrecision(), event.getDeviceId(),
                    event.getEdgeFlags());
            me.setLocation(x, y);

            if (!me.equals(event)) {
                // deals the Event
                view.onTouchEvent(me);
            }

            // debug
            if (actionResolved == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                Log.v("tag",
                        "#" + actionPointerIndex + " Rawx:" + rawX + " rawy:"
                                + rawY + " x:" + x + " y:" + y + " "
                                + view.toString());
            }
        }

    }

   
    
    
    

//  @Override
 //   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
  //  {
 //       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.touchsample, menu);
  //      return true;
 //   }
    
    
    
    
    
    public class secondDrum implements OnTouchListener
    {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            
            dumpEvent(event);
            
            
            AudioManager bongos2 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            float curVolume2 = bongos2.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float maxVolume2 = bongos2.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float leftvolume2 = curVolume2/maxVolume2;
            float rightVolume2 = curVolume2/maxVolume2;
            int priority2 = 1;
            int no_loop2 = 0;
            float normal_playback_rate2=1.0f;
            
            fx.play(sfxId2, leftvolume2, rightVolume2, priority2, no_loop2, normal_playback_rate2);
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
        
        public class thirdDrum implements OnTouchListener
        {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                    
                    dumpEvent(event);
                    AudioManager bongos3 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    float curVolume = bongos3.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    float maxVolume = bongos3.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    float leftVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                    float rightVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                    int priority = 1;       
                    int no_loop = 0;
                    float normal_playback_rate = 2.0f;
                    fx.play(sfxId3, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
                    return false;
                            
                    //return false;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        
            public class forthDrum implements OnTouchListener
            {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    
                    dumpEvent(event);
                    AudioManager bongos4 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    float curVolume = bongos4.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    float maxVolume = bongos4.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    float leftVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                    float rightVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                    int priority = 1;       
                    int no_loop = 0;
                    float normal_playback_rate = 2.0f;
                    fx.play(sfxId4, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);  
                    return false;
                    //return false;
                    
                }
                
            }
    


            
            
            
    
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        
            dumpEvent(event);
        
            AudioManager bongos = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            float curVolume = bongos.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float maxVolume = bongos.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float leftVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
            float rightVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
            int priority = 1;       
            int no_loop = 0;
            float normal_playback_rate = 1.0f;
            fx.play(sfxId, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);       
            //return false;
            //index of the pointer which starts this Event
            
            final int actionPointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

            // resolve the action as a basic type (up, down or move)
            int actionResolved = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            if (actionResolved < 7 && actionResolved > 4) {
                actionResolved = actionResolved - 5;
            }

            if (actionResolved == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                for (int ptrIndex = 0; ptrIndex < event.getPointerCount(); ptrIndex++) {
                    // only one event for all move events.
                    dealEvent(ptrIndex, event, view, actionResolved);
                    Log.v("tag", "move" + ptrIndex);
                }

            } else {
                dealEvent(actionPointerIndex, event, view, actionResolved);
            }

            return false;
            }
    
    
        private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
        {
            final String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE", "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            final int action = event.getAction();
            final int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        
        
            if(actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
            {
                sb.append("(pid " ).append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
                sb.append(")" );
            }
        
        
            sb.append("[");
        
        
            for (int i = 0; i <event.getPointerCount(); i++)
            {
                sb.append("#").append(i);
                sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
                sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
                sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
                if(i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                    sb.append(";");
            }
        
            sb.append("]");
            Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
        }
    
    

        private ArrayList<View> getChildViews(final View view) {
            final ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                final ViewGroup v = ((ViewGroup) view);
                if (v.getChildCount() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        views.add(v.getChildAt(i));
                    }

                }
            }
            return views;
        }

        private ArrayList<View> getTouchedViews(final int x, final int y) {

            View lastTouchedView = null;
            final ArrayList<View> touchedViews = new ArrayList<View>();
            final ArrayList<View> possibleViews = new ArrayList<View>();

            if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
                possibleViews.add(parent);
                for (int i = 0; i < possibleViews.size(); i--) {
                    final View view = possibleViews.get(i);

                    final int location[] = { 0, 0 };
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

                    if (((view.getHeight() + location[1] >= y)
                            & (view.getWidth() + location[0] >= x)
                            & (view.getLeft() <= x) & (view.getTop() <= y))
                        || view instanceof FrameLayout) {
                        if (this.multiTouchViews.contains(view)){
                            lastTouchedView = view;
                        }
                        possibleViews.addAll(getChildViews(view));
                    }
                }
                //ArrayList<View> touchedViews = new ArrayList<View>();
                if (lastTouchedView != null){
                        touchedViews.add(lastTouchedView);
                }

                return touchedViews;
            }
                return possibleViews;
        }

    //@Override
    //public void onCreate(final Bundle instance) {
    //  super.onCreate(instance);
        


    //public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.touchsample);
            
            fx=new SoundPool(1100, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1100);
            fxMap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            
            fxMap.put(sfxId, fx.load(this, R.raw.bongo_left, 1));
            fxMap.put(sfxId2, fx.load(this, R.raw.bongo_right, 1));
            fxMap.put(sfxId3, fx.load(this, R.raw.bongo_left, 1));
            fxMap.put(sfxId4, fx.load(this, R.raw.bongo_right, 1));
            
            parent = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
            parent.setOnTouchListener(this);
            mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getApplicationContext())
                    .getScaledTouchSlop();
            
        }   
        
        
        
     private boolean pointInView(final float localX, final float localY,
             final float slop, final float width, final float height) {
            return localX >= -slop && localY >= -slop && localX < ((width) + slop)
            && localY < ((height) + slop);
    }
    
}
```

---

and the extension:

```
package sample.app.touchsample;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Multitouch extends TouchsampleActivity{
    
    

    private ImageView imageview1, imageview2, imageview3, imageview4;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    SoundPool fx;
    HashMap <Integer, Integer> fxMap;
        
    int sfxId=1;
    int sfxId2=2;
    int sfxId3=3;
    int sfxId4=4;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.touchsample);
        
        fx=new SoundPool(1100, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1100);
        fxMap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            
        fxMap.put(sfxId, fx.load(this, R.raw.bongo_left, 1));
        fxMap.put(sfxId2, fx.load(this, R.raw.bongo_right, 1));
        fxMap.put(sfxId3, fx.load(this, R.raw.bongo_left, 1));
        fxMap.put(sfxId4, fx.load(this, R.raw.bongo_right, 1));
            
        
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);     
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
        
        ImageView view2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        view2.setOnTouchListener(new secondDrum());
        
        ImageView view3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        view3.setOnTouchListener(new thirdDrum());
        
        ImageView view4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        view4.setOnTouchListener(new forthDrum());
        
        }
    

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
    
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:               
                //dumpEvent(event);
        
                AudioManager bongos = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float curVolume = bongos.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = bongos.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float leftVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                float rightVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                int priority = 1;       
                int no_loop = 0;
                float normal_playback_rate = 1.0f;
                fx.play(sfxId, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);       
        
                return false;
        
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        
                break;
        
        }
    
            class secondDrum implements OnTouchListener
            {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    switch (event.getAction())
                    {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                
                //dumpEvent(event);
                
                AudioManager bongos2 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float curVolume2 = bongos2.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume2 = bongos2.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float leftvolume2 = curVolume2/maxVolume2;
                float rightVolume2 = curVolume2/maxVolume2;
                int priority2 = 1;
                int no_loop2 = 0;
                float normal_playback_rate2=1.0f;
                fx.play(sfxId2, leftvolume2, rightVolume2, priority2, no_loop2, normal_playback_rate2);
                return false;
                
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                
                        break;
            }
            
            
            class thirdDrum implements OnTouchListener
            {

                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
                {
            
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {           
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                
                        //dumpEvent(event);
                        AudioManager bongos3 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        float curVolume = bongos3.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        float maxVolume = bongos3.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        float leftVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                        float rightVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                        int priority = 1;       
                        int no_loop = 0;
                        float normal_playback_rate = 2.0f;
                        fx.play(sfxId3, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
                    
                        return false;
            
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                
                        break;
                    }
            
            class forthDrum implements OnTouchListener
            {
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                    {
                            
                        switch (event.getAction())
                        {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                
                                AudioManager bongos4 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                                float curVolume = bongos4.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                float maxVolume = bongos4.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                float leftVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                                float rightVolume = curVolume/maxVolume;
                                int priority = 1;       
                                int no_loop = 0;
                                float normal_playback_rate = 2.0f;
                                fx.play(sfxId4, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);  
                                return false;
                                
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                
                                break;
                            
                                }
                            return true;
                                }
                            }
                    return true;
                        }
                    }
            return true;
                }
            }
        return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: make sure you don't exceed the size of the array as it is the exception which is thrown "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException". You need to take care of this as there is no check over size of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < possibleViews.size(); i--)
```

it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < possibleViews.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
```

This is the major thing you need. It indicates you have an array of size `12` but you're trying to access element number `-1`. This is usually because you run off the end of the array (counting down in this case). It's in the Android runtime but you'll find you probably need to walk up the stack trace to find the errant code (which is almost *always* your code).

In all likelihood, it's the following line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < possibleViews.size(); i--)
```

in `getTouchedViews()`, the third step up the stack and the first one that appears to be non-Android code:

```
07-30 16:57:08.613: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at
    sample.app.touchsample.TouchsampleActivity
        .getTouchedViews(TouchsampleActivity.java:365)
```

This loop starts at zero and counts down (immediately to `-1`) so is almost certainly your your problem. Use `i++` instead.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs when you try to access a element out of your array index.

E.g. Consider your array has 10 element's and you try to access element 12 or 13 this would result in  a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Look into those loops again and see where the array index is going out of bounds. Also remember arrays in java start with a index of 0 and not 1.

Comment: you mean i should type it this way?  private final ArrayList[] recentTouchedViewsIndex = new ArrayList[0];

Comment: The error does not result because how you declare the array. It is because the way you are trying to access the array is incorrect. Also ArrayList is a Array you sure you want a Array of ArrayList...

Comment: Look into the getTouchedViews function. Here you are decrementing the value of i. I starts at 0, and instead of doing i++ you are doing i-- which makes your code access element at -1 from the possibleViews list. Hence you are getting the ArrayOutOfBoundException.